# find elements by xpath selenium Phantomjs

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, rselenium

I'm using `Rselenium` for scraping. For this, I have installed `java` and `JDK's`, `chromedriver`, `selenium server standalone` and the headless browser `phantomjs` in my VM instance of Google Cloud.

I need to catch the text of the first rating:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'chrome', port = 4444L)
remDr$open()
remDr$setWindowSize(1280L, 1024L)
remDr$navigate("https://www.ratebeer.com/reviews/sullerica-1561/294423")
text_post = remDr$findElements("xpath",'//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')

text_post
## list()
```

Finally `text_post` is empty.

However, If I test the same script on my local laptop with RSelenium, chrome browser and the same XPath, it's a success!

What's going on?
Is it due to using Phantomjs?

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you can use the *xpath* as:

```
//div[@id="root"]//span[contains(.,'20')]//following::div[contains(@class,'LinesEllipsis')]
```

**Note**: As the elements are dynamically generated elements you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *Elements to be visible*.

Comment: @MarioM. Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a heavyweight, third-party dependency. That site uses graphql `POST` requests under the hood in asynchronous XHR requests to retrieve the data. You can see it if you open Developer Tools and[image]

I did a "Copy POST Data" (usually the same or rly similar context menu item in all browsers) and un-minimized the graphql query in the Response tab just to show you what it is and to also, perhaps, make it easier for you to see the query and augment it on your own (what I just said is out of scope for "but what about…" follow on questions in comments; please file a new question if you want help with that).

```
'[
    {
        "operationName": "beer",
        "query": "query beer($beerId: ID!) {\n  info: beer(id: $beerId) {\n    id\n    name\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n",
        "variables": {
            "beerId": "294423"
        }
    },
    {
        "operationName": "beer",
        "query": "query beer($beerId: ID!) {\n  info: beer(id: $beerId) {\n    id\n    name\n    styleScore\n    overallScore\n    averageRating\n    ratingCount\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n",
        "variables": {
            "beerId": "294423"
        }
    },
    {
        "operationName": "beerReviews",
        "query": "query beerReviews($beerId: ID!, $authorId: ID, $order: ReviewOrder, $after: ID) {\n  beerReviewsArr: beerReviews(beerId: $beerId, authorId: $authorId, order: $order, after: $after) {\n    items {\n      ...ReviewItem\n      __typename\n    }\n    totalCount\n    last\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ReviewItem on Review {\n  id\n  comment\n  score\n  scores {\n    appearance\n    aroma\n    flavor\n    mouthfeel\n    overall\n    __typename\n  }\n  author {\n    id\n    username\n    reviewCount\n    __typename\n  }\n  checkin {\n    id\n    place {\n      id\n      name\n      city\n      state {\n        id\n        name\n        __typename\n      }\n      country {\n        id\n        name\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  servedIn\n  likeCount\n  likedByMe\n  createdAt\n  updatedAt\n  __typename\n}\n",
        "variables": {
            "beerId": "294423",
            "first": 7,
            "order": "RECENT"
        }
    }
]' -> graphql_query
```

We will need to scrunch that back into one line for the API call (which I do with the `gsub()` below. We also need to manually specify the content type and ensure `httr` does not try to mangle the body data by setting the encoding to `raw`:

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://beta.ratebeer.com/v1/api/graphql/",
  httr::content_type("application/json"),
  encode = "raw",
  body = gsub("\n", " ", graphql_query),
  httr::verbose()
) -> res
```

Now we have a structured, but heavily nested, list with your ifo in it. Pretty sure you're after `items` below:

```
str(httr::content(res), 4)
## List of 3
##  $ :List of 1
##   ..$ data:List of 1
##   .. ..$ info:List of 3
##   .. .. ..$ id        : chr "294423"
##   .. .. ..$ name      : chr "Sullerica 1561"
##   .. .. ..$ __typename: chr "Beer"
##  $ :List of 1
##   ..$ data:List of 1
##   .. ..$ info:List of 7
##   .. .. ..$ id           : chr "294423"
##   .. .. ..$ name         : chr "Sullerica 1561"
##   .. .. ..$ styleScore   : num 35.1
##   .. .. ..$ overallScore : num 51.8
##   .. .. ..$ averageRating: num 3.25
##   .. .. ..$ ratingCount  : int 21
##   .. .. ..$ __typename   : chr "Beer"
##  $ :List of 1
##   ..$ data:List of 1
##   .. ..$ beerReviewsArr:List of 4
##   .. .. ..$ items     :List of 10
##   .. .. ..$ totalCount: int 21
##   .. .. ..$ last      : chr "7177326"
##   .. .. ..$ __typename: chr "ReviewList"
```

It does only have 10 out of 21 so scroll down in your browser window with Developer Tools open and look at the second `POST` request that gets made, see what parameters changed and now you will have an even better idea of how to access the site's back-end API vs have to scrape for content.